# Transfer 40000+ files usnig rsync between two servers

Tags: linux, rsync, file-transfer

I have a problem with transfer files between two Linux servers in the same network. On source server I have directory with 40055 small files, directory size is 34 GB. I tried to transfer those files with rsync command:

```
rsync -ah --progress --inplace /dir/dir_with_files user@server:/dir/destination_dir
```

After transfer, on destination server I have directory with size 108 GB not 34 GB

Blocks on partitions are the same.

I did the same thing with scp but the problem is the same.

Comment: Any sparse files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complete retention of everything, try:

```
rsync --archive --hard-links --sparse-files --acls --xattrs source dest
```

Then to verify correctness, you can do something like (assuming no spaces in your file names): `for file in *; do md5sum $file >> /tmp/sums.txt; done` and then `diff` sums.txt on both servers. The md5summing is going to take a while, though.

If you do have spaces in your file names, construct something with `find` and/or `xargs`

BTW, what does `du --bytes -hs` say? That way, you rule out block size.